# NSTextFieldCell standard text drawing position

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextfieldcell

Is there a way to get the position where the text in an NSTextFieldCell will be drawn when  you call [super drawInteriorWithFrame:cellFrame inView:controlView] in drawInteriorWithFrame:inView: ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text rectangle is the return value of `titleRectForBounds:` passed `cellFrame` with mysterious 2px horizontal inset:

```
// this code ...
NSRect bounds = NSInsetRect(cellFrame, 2, 0); // dont ask me why
NSRect titleRect = [self titleRectForBounds:bounds];
[self.attributedStringValue drawInRect:titleRect];

// ... is equivalent to
[super drawInteriorWithFrame:cellFrame inView:controlView];
```

I don't know for sure what those 2px stand for, it's been figured out experimentally by trying all operating systems from 10.6 to 10.9-preview with all possible text field configurations. It seems there is always this unconditional 2px inset. One can easily confirm the default implementation does call `NSInsetRect` with exactly those parameters by setting a breakpoint and looking into debugger disassembly.

My guess: the 2px inset is needed to avoid clipping when starting or stopping letter sticks out of bounds for sake of better typography (zoom in and look closely where W or A letters are *really* rendered compared to say H or P).

Comment: [This](http://www.quantum-step.com/download/sources/mySTEP/AppKit/Sources/NSCell.m) might give some insight. Look at the drawInteriorWithFrame method. The bezel type seems to be what requires the inset of either 1 or 2 pixels. Note: It's also in the vertical direction in Quantum-Step; I do not know if that's the case in Cocoa on Mac OS X.